# Is there a prescribed method to determine order of combat within the three phases?

Tags: combat, initiative, avatar-legends

My group played our first round of combat in Avatar Legends and definitely stumbled through it.

It went fairly well, but there was a confusing point when we weren't sure how to determine order of characters within the three phases of combat and couldn't find anything in the core rulebook.

How is combat order determined within the phases? Is it left up to the table?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Resolve approaches in priority order. PCs choose first but all techniques are resolved simultaneously.

> Resolve the approaches in order, starting with all **defend and maneuver** approaches, followed by all **advance and attack** approaches, followed by all **evade and observe** approaches. When resolving each approach, PCs who chose that approach roll the **stance move** to see how many techniques they may use. NPCs use techniques equal to 1 + their current balance as it stands specifically at the start of that  approach.
>
> PCs choose their techniques first, and then the NPCs choose their techniques to use. All techniques within an approach are functionally resolved simultaneously.
>
> If anyone is taken out or loses their balance, they don't suffer those consequences yet, even if their approach hasn't been resolved yet. The same goes for statuses (page 151) -- the effect of the status doesn’t kick in until the exchange ends.
>
> -- "Step-By-Step Exchange", *Avatar Legends* p.149

If PCs are for instance fighting each other, or otherwise have a reason not to know what techniques other PCs are using when they make their choice, PCs should choose their techniques in secret and reveal them simultaneously.

#### Narration, Multiple Exchanges, and Advanced Techniques

Exchanges aren't all there is to a fight scene, they're just basically your atomic fight unit. Once everyone's exchange is complete, the fight results like losing balance or inflicting status start taking effect, but also consider pausing to allow other dramatic things to happen and re-evaluate the fight. Maybe enough of the big names have gone down that this isn't an exchange-worthy fight anymore. Whatever the case it's very rare that the narrative of a fight scene is just "nonstop exchanges until one side can't fight anymore". But let's consider the narrative of a fight scene.

The extended combat example, beginning on page 241, runs through three exchanges at the beginning of a fight scene, after engagement is decided, and each one is resolved in its entirety, from approach choice through to resolution. From a narrative perspective this makes total sense - each exchange is its own story in the fight, and approaching the fight by resolving exchanges serially allows each story to play out a full arc - and it's also likely how the fight would be shot cinematically if the idea is to give the audience an impression of these characters going through their arc, rather than trying to play up the chaos and confusion of the fight by cross-cutting through a bunch of different showdowns as they progress. From a mechanical perspective this isn't strictly what should happen, but it's fine to organize things this way because none of the choices made in the example of play need a higher level of mechanical rigor.

Sometimes you might even want things to be more cinematically complex, like when half the PCs hold off the guards while the other half help Sage Niuan confront Sage Bai and the sage confrontation plays out at double tempo, two exchanges for every one with the rank-and-file guards. Sometimes, depending on how your PCs are trained and what techniques they select, you the GM might not even have sole control over "the camera" - PCs can use techniques to control who they're engaged in the fight with. A focused weaponmaster can try to **Seize Position** and **Counterstrike** somebody in the next fight over. A passionate airbender could similarly use **Cannonball** to jump lanes and lock horns with somebody else, *impair*ing them and using **Pressure** to shut down the attack approach with a literal pressure wall. A more highly trained but no less passionate earthbender could just explode off a mountainside and **Charge** into anybody, then knock them out of frame with an **Earthen Gauntlet**. How do you deal with this without compromising your cinematic vision?

**If every exchange is equal, reserve the right to activate your trap card.** If you have a group bracing to set up a **Shield Wall** and **Retaliate**, does your earthbender get in free hits when they jump over that they wouldn't have if they were in the fight to begin with? Just because they went first by narrative coincidence? Or if you have that weaponmaster who likes to **Counterstrike**, do they only get to do it in their exchange because it's the only one where they know what approaches were decided on, unless they're going last by narrative coincidence? If you have a party that likes to dynamically switch up engagements, treating exchanges as parallel can help resolve these mechanical concerns, but if that would chop up narration too much you only need to nail a few things down up front. Decide and reveal approaches as a whole, then as a GM decide but don't reveal what actions all your **defend and maneuver** NPCs are taking. You can narrate exchanges in different parts of the scene one after the other just fine after that; this is enough knowledge for everybody to make their own decisions about which specific techniques to use. If somebody wants to use an **attack and advance** technique to jump over and beat down on someone with a defense lined up that they don't know what it is, that's a risk they take.

**If one exchange has dramatic priority, you should probably write a move about why that is.** Again, this isn't strictly necessary unless your PCs have and use techniques that let them switch up engagements. Write up a player-facing move so everybody knows the stakes. If this is one of those end-of-season things where somebody has to go fight in the spirit maelstrom it might get pretty hefty, but here's the simplest form of things:

> **(High Intensity | Fever Pitch):** Engaging (Lord Bedli | Super Lord Bedli) is both necessary and dangerous to everyone involved. Anyone engaged with them fights through (2 | 3) exchanges for every one with their more conventional forces. Resolve any attempts to engage into/disengage from the fight with them at the end of all external exchanges, and be ready to (**rely on your training** | **push your luck**).

As you might be able to tell by the form of it, this should only come out in those scenarios where you want the fight to spotlight the isolation and danger of a foe, and make tagging into or tagging out of the heightened conflict a dramatic event in its own right. If somebody uses a technique to change engagement, you can still give them the effects of that technique (and its followups, if any) when you resolve the attempt with help from one of the basic moves, and since you're doing it at the end of an exchange any status and fatigue will apply immediately.

**Regardless of what you do, keep two things in mind.** First, it's fine if PCs in successive exchanges make decisions taking into account what's happening elsewhere - taking risks if other PCs are doing poorly, holding back if they're doing well - because even if this is supposed to be "happening simultaneously", that's not the way the scene was shot and nothing breaks up the flow worse than blowing the whistle to point out a technical inconsistency. Second, you shouldn't re-revaluate engagements or call for major non-combat moves until you've given everybody equal turns (factored for acceleration) in the exchange. Everybody lined up for engagements in order to accomplish something or otherwise assert themselves, so let everybody see it through before you pull the camera back to follow what the guy who threw the smoke bomb and ran is doing.

Answer (score 6):

### Break the combat into smaller exchanges. All techniques from the same exchange and approach are resolved simultaneously.

Even before approaches are chosen, combat should be **broken up into separate exchanges** based on who is engaged with whom (core book, p. 147, emphasis mine):

> Every combatant is almost never engaged with every other combatant. Different fighters face off against different foes, saying, “I’ll hold them off,” or “Don’t worry, I’ve got this guy.” **Each set of engaged fighters has its own exchanges** […] The more that you can break up exchanges into bouts of three or fewer combatants, the more effective your combat exchanges will be.

Although these exchanges happen simultaneously in the fiction, they don’t all get the spotlight at the same time (p. 240):

> If all the companions are in a fight with multiple opponents, it’s a good idea to split exchanges up into groups. You can switch between these groups to provide every player the spotlight, and allow PCs to use techniques to shift from one to the other, or to make moves in between exchanges.

“All techniques within an approach are functionally resolved simultaneously” (p. 149)—not for the entire field of combat, but for whichever exchange the spotlight is currently focused on. Thus, techniques are resolved *per approach per exchange.*

We can see this in the extended combat example (p. 240-243), which is split into three exchanges among three foes. Each exchange is resolved in its entirety, from start to finish, before the spotlight shifts to other characters in other exchanges. In other words, it follows these steps:<sup>1</sup>

1. Exchange A, Defend & Maneuver
2. Exchange A, Advance & Attack
3. Exchange A, Evade & Observe
4. Exchange B, Defend & Maneuver
5. Exchange B, Advance & Attack
6. Exchange B, Evade & Observe
7. Exchange C, Defend & Maneuver
8. Exchange C, Advance & Attack
9. Exchange C, Evade & Observe

There are no hard rules for when to shift the spotlight; it’s left to the GM’s cinematic instincts. The above method has the advantage of lingering on each exchange in a narratively satisfying way. On the other hand, if any characters are planning to change whom they’re engaged with (e.g., through the Seize a Position technique, p. 154) or otherwise interrupt other exchanges, then the GM might try something like this:

1. Exchange A, Defend & Maneuver
2. Exchange B, Defend & Maneuver
3. Exchange C, Defend & Maneuver
4. Exchange A, Advance & Attack
5. Exchange B, Advance & Attack
6. Exchange C, Advance & Attack
7. Exchange A, Evade & Observe
8. Exchange B, Evade & Observe
9. Exchange C, Evade & Observe

Note that even in the above example, you are **not** resolving every single Defend & Maneuver approach in the entire combat at the same time (nor every single Advance & Attack approach, etc.): you resolve Defend & Maneuver for one set of characters, then shift the spotlight to a different exchange and resolve Defend & Maneuver for those characters, and so on.

The important takeaway is that by splitting the companions among multiple foes, the GM cuts back on the number of techniques that need to be resolved simultaneously, thus cutting back the overall clutter of combat.

---

<sup>1. Many of the steps are skipped, since not every approach is used in every exchange. The order of events that actually happens is: 1) Exchange A, Advance & Attack; 2) Exchange B, Defend & Maneuver; 3) Exchange B, Advance & Attack; 4) Exchange C, Evade & Observe.</sup>